# VS2013 pro пропал Intellisense в одном проекте

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli

Собственно вопрос в этом, мало того что не предлагает так даже не подсвечивает (типы переменных, классы итд...)
Создаю новый проект - работает, в предыдущих тоже. Но в основном проекте не работает. 
Использую С++/CLI, это я к тому что: СЕРВИС->Параметры->Текстовый редактор-> и тут CLI (CLR) нету, а в разделе C/C++ intelliSense нет, а вот в C# настройки IntelliSense есть. 
Вот что может быть то?

Comment: удаление sdf файла не помогло.

Comment: проблема с инклудами.